# Infinite scroll without using a plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, infinite-scroll

I'm new to rails, and I don't know how to create an infinite scroll to my application. I have my javascript code as follows:

```
<div id = "container1"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "shirts/first",
            type : "GET"
        });  
        $("#name").autocomplete({
            source : "shirts/autocomplete",
            autoFocus : false,
            minLength : 1,
            select : function(event, ui) {
                document.getElementById("name").value = ui.item.value;
                $.ajax({
                    url : "shirts/show?name=" + ui.item.value,
                    type : "GET"
                });
            }
        });
        jQuery(function() {
            if ($('.pagination').length) {
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                    var url;
                    url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
                    if (url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50) {
                        $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...");
                        return $.getScript(url);
                    }
                });
                return $(window).scroll();
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "shirts/first",
                type: "GET"
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is my .js.erb file :

```
$("#container1").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'shirts/first')%>");
```

Am I handling the AJAX function correctly? When I check in firebug the browser is loading the first page twice and is not fetching the other pages!

Should I do any changes to the controller?

Comment: Have you had any pagination added from your controller/views ? Just check with it once.